# What could be causing these BSODS? ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY and MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, bsod

I recently bought a second hand PC and put new hard drives in it, and installed a new version of Windows 10. I have updated the BIOS to the latest version, updated to the latest graphics card drivers, and have run Samsung Magician as well. I have gotten two blue screens in the last few days and I'm wondering what could be causing them? Crash dumps are below. First occurred while doing nothing in particular, second with about 10 tabs open in Chrome.

I have read that this could be a virtual memory or hard drive error, or a faulty RAM stick - what do you guys think? Should I start swapping out sticks and running memtest?

Greatly appreciate any input, thanks for your time :)

```
Operating System
    Windows 10 Home 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i7 6700 @ 3.40GHz    27 °C
    Skylake 14nm Technology
RAM
    32.0GB Dual-Channel Unknown @ 1066MHz (15-15-15-35)
Motherboard
    MSI Z170A GAMING M5 (MS-7977) (U3E1)    30 °C
Graphics
    S27C350 (1920x1080@60Hz)
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 (NVIDIA)  25 °C
Storage
    1863GB Western Digital WDC WD2003FZEX-00SRLA0 (SATA )   28 °C
    465GB Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB (Unknown (SSD))
Optical Drives
    No optical disk drives detected
Audio
    High Definition Audio Device
```

First Dump

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17134.12 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\080818-6046-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 17134 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`6c200000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`6c5ba1f0
Debug session time: Wed Aug  8 16:32:12.690 2018 (UTC + 10:00)
System Uptime: 6 days 2:02:10.017
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
.................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..................................................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck BE, {ffffeb0c071879f4, 8a00000000200021, ffffee8b7b037360, a}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for win32k.sys
Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault+f8001 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY (be)
An attempt was made to write to readonly memory.  The guilty driver is on the
stack trace (and is typically the current instruction pointer).
When possible, the guilty driver's name (Unicode string) is printed on
the bugcheck screen and saved in KiBugCheckDriver.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffeb0c071879f4, Virtual address for the attempted write.
Arg2: 8a00000000200021, PTE contents.
Arg3: ffffee8b7b037360, (reserved)
Arg4: 000000000000000a, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  MS-7977

SYSTEM_SKU:  Default string

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.H0

BIOS_DATE:  05/15/2018

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z170A GAMING M5 (MS-7977)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffeb0c071879f4

BUGCHECK_P2: 8a00000000200021

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffee8b7b037360

BUGCHECK_P4: a

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d50

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: C2'00000000 (cache) C2'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xBE

PROCESS_NAME:  MsMpEng.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  JINBOX3000

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  08-08-2018 16:50:06.0616

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17134.12 x86fre

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffee8b7b037360 -- (.trap 0xffffee8b7b037360)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=ff00000fffffffff rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=ffffee0000007370 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8036c2bbec7 rsp=ffffee8b7b0374f0 rbp=ffffee8b7b037651
 r8=ffffee0000007000  r9=ffffeb0c071879d0 r10=000000004025d7df
r11=000000000019190d r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
nt!MiUnlinkPageFromList+0x3f7:
fffff803`6c2bbec7 6645895924      mov     word ptr [r9+24h],r11w ds:ffffeb0c`071879f4=????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8036c40b359 to fffff8036c398430

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffee8b`7b0371a8 fffff803`6c40b359 : 00000000`000000be ffffeb0c`071879f4 8a000000`00200021 ffffee8b`7b037360 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffee8b`7b0371b0 fffff803`6c2ad606 : 00000000`00000003 8a000000`00200021 ffffee8b`7b0372f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault+0xf8001
ffffee8b`7b0371f0 fffff803`6c3a5ada : 00000000`0000001c ffff9a05`00000000 ffffc281`9e3c8180 fffff803`6c290c6f : nt!MmAccessFault+0x3f6
ffffee8b`7b037360 fffff803`6c2bbec7 : fffff803`6c5dc030 00000000`00000dd0 ffffee00`00007000 fffff803`6c5db8c0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x31a
ffffee8b`7b0374f0 fffff803`6c2bec9f : ffffee00`00007370 ffffee8b`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!MiUnlinkPageFromList+0x3f7
ffffee8b`7b037580 fffff803`6c30e464 : ffff9a05`8c960400 ffff9a05`8f500c01 00000000`00000000 ffffee8b`00000000 : nt!MmPurgeSection+0x43f
ffffee8b`7b0376b0 fffff804`542c32b2 : ffffee8b`00000000 ffffd80f`0176cc00 ffffee8b`7b537400 ffffee8b`00000000 : nt!CcPurgeCacheSection+0x94
ffffee8b`7b037770 fffff804`54379d10 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffee8b`00000000 ffffee8b`7b537400 : Ntfs!NtfsPurgeCacheSection+0x26
ffffee8b`7b0377a0 fffff804`543a81aa : ffffd80f`0176cab0 ffffee8b`7b537400 ffffd80f`0176cee8 ffffd80f`0176cc00 : Ntfs!NtfsDeleteFile+0xf50
ffffee8b`7b037a80 fffff804`543aec19 : ffff9a05`8a3cc018 ffff9a05`89063010 ffffee8b`7b537390 ffff9a05`8c5d8080 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCleanup+0x2bca
ffffee8b`7b037f50 fffff803`6c39b947 : ffffee8b`7b537390 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCleanupCallout+0x19
ffffee8b`7b037f80 fffff803`6c39b90d : 00000000`00006000 ffff9a05`8c5d8080 00000000`00000004 fffff803`6c25841a : nt!KxSwitchKernelStackCallout+0x27
ffffee8b`7b5371a0 fffff803`6c25841a : fffffeff`00000012 00000000`00000012 ffff8584`c246cc98 ffffd80f`0176cab8 : nt!KiSwitchKernelStackContinue
ffffee8b`7b5371c0 fffff803`6c25825e : fffff804`543aec00 00000000`00006000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExpandKernelStackAndCalloutOnStackSegment+0x12a
ffffee8b`7b537240 fffff803`6c258115 : 00000000`00000000 ffffee8b`7b537390 00000000`00000000 ffff9a05`8e1890f8 : nt!KiExpandKernelStackAndCalloutSwitchStack+0x9e
ffffee8b`7b5372b0 fffff803`6c2580cd : fffff804`543aec00 ffffee8b`7b537390 00000000`00000000 ffffee8b`7b5373d0 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal+0x35
ffffee8b`7b537310 fffff804`5439c225 : ffffee8b`7b537400 ffffee8b`7b537400 ffff9a05`89063010 ffff9a05`00000000 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0x1d
ffffee8b`7b537350 fffff803`6c2841a9 : ffff9a05`8e189010 ffffee8b`7b537750 ffff9a05`89063010 ffff9a05`89b85df0 : Ntfs!NtfsFsdCleanup+0x175
ffffee8b`7b537680 fffff804`538d7207 : ffffee8b`7b537750 fffff804`538d53b4 ffff9a05`89063010 00000000`00000012 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffee8b`7b5376c0 fffff804`538d51c6 : ffffee8b`7b537750 ffff9a05`8dd56580 ffff9a05`89b85df0 ffff9a05`8dd56580 : FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x157
ffffee8b`7b537730 fffff803`6c2841a9 : ffff9a05`9438a080 fffff803`6c281c75 ffff9a05`89063010 fffff803`6c28db64 : FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0xb6
ffffee8b`7b537790 fffff803`6c71197e : ffff9a05`9438a080 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffee8b`7b5377d0 fffff803`6c6fb152 : ffff9a05`9438a050 00000000`00000001 ffffd80e`00000000 00000000`00007ffc : nt!IopCloseFile+0x15e
ffffee8b`7b537860 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObCloseHandleTableEntry+0x212


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  5950b7c7abf2851118715e0023089dd72d86f3ec

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  716d5aff6292149a482996d8050179168cdc67c3

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  068f4e0cee4b4ecd1cd874b7a300e6fa4877c357

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault+f8001
fffff803`6c40b359 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  2c8440cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault+f8001

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5b3f12f4

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17134.165

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  f8001

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault

BUCKET_ID:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault

TARGET_TIME:  2018-08-08T06:32:12.000Z

OSBUILD:  17134

OSSERVICEPACK:  165

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2018-07-06 16:57:56

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180410-1804

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs4_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  287f

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xbe_nt!miraisedirqlfault

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {1c5b4d11-09e0-def3-d2d0-70a11d69b92d}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

And the second dump:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17134.12 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\081218-4375-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 17134 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff802`6d218000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff802`6d5d21f0
Debug session time: Sun Aug 12 12:19:44.253 2018 (UTC + 10:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:30:16.467
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
...................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.............
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1A, {41792, ffff898058c0f208, 4000, 0}

Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( ONE_BIT )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

5: kd> -analyze -v
       ^ Syntax error in '-analyze -v'
5: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041792, A corrupt PTE has been detected. Parameter 2 contains the address of
    the PTE. Parameters 3/4 contain the low/high parts of the PTE.
Arg2: ffff898058c0f208
Arg3: 0000000000004000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  MS-7977

SYSTEM_SKU:  Default string

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.H0

BIOS_DATE:  05/15/2018

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z170A GAMING M5 (MS-7977)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 41792

BUGCHECK_P2: ffff898058c0f208

BUGCHECK_P3: 4000

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BIT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41792

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d50

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: C2'00000000 (cache) C2'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  JINBOX3000

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  08-12-2018 12:31:32.0296

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17134.12 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8788`45696d08 fffff802`6d3f27aa : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041792 ffff8980`58c0f208 00000000`00004000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff8788`45696d10 fffff802`6d292b79 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00004000 ffff8788`456973f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVa+0x15e06a
ffff8788`45696e20 fffff802`6d292f82 : ffff8788`456973f0 ffff8980`58c0f208 ffff8788`00000000 ffff8788`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x299
ffff8788`45696f00 fffff802`6d292f82 : ffff8788`456973f0 ffff89c4`c02c6078 ffff8788`00000001 ffff8788`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a2
ffff8788`45696fe0 fffff802`6d292f82 : ffff8788`456973f0 ffff89c4`e2601630 ffff8788`00000002 ffff8788`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a2
ffff8788`456970c0 fffff802`6d291497 : ffff8788`456973f0 ffff89c4`e2713008 00000000`00000003 fffff802`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a2
ffff8788`456971a0 fffff802`6d28d3b3 : ffff8788`456973f0 ffffb889`00000001 ffffb889`00000000 ffffb889`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTables+0x1e7
ffff8788`45697290 fffff802`6d6cc391 : ffffb889`fa0b4700 ffffb889`00000000 ffffb889`f7319e80 ffffb889`fa0b4700 : nt!MiDeleteVad+0x8d3
ffff8788`456975c0 fffff802`6d6cc1b3 : ffffb889`fe18ec90 ffffb889`fe18ec90 ffffb889`f7319e80 ffffb889`fe877580 : nt!MiCleanVad+0x4d
ffff8788`456975f0 fffff802`6d6cbefd : ffffffff`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8788`45697801 ffffb889`fe877080 : nt!MmCleanProcessAddressSpace+0x11f
ffff8788`45697670 fffff802`6d6d3d38 : ffffb889`fe877080 ffffcc8a`27b69970 ffff8788`45697888 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspRundownSingleProcess+0x129
ffff8788`456976f0 fffff802`6d7c3103 : 00000000`00000000 ffffdd00`6b090101 000000b1`81838000 fffff802`6d2a38db : nt!PspExitThread+0x5ac
ffff8788`456977f0 fffff802`6d2a6360 : 00000000`00000000 ffffb889`fe82d1f0 ffffb889`00000000 0000000c`ae5ff5ec : nt!KiSchedulerApcTerminate+0x33
ffff8788`45697830 fffff802`6d3b4500 : 00000000`00000320 ffff8788`456978c0 00000000`00000000 fffff802`00000000 : nt!KiDeliverApc+0x3a0
ffff8788`456978c0 fffff802`6d3c0aea : ffffb889`fa0b4700 000000b1`821ff608 ffff8788`456979d8 ffffb889`fdb20690 : nt!KiInitiateUserApc+0x70
ffff8788`45697a00 00007fff`35299f34 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceExit+0x9f
000000b1`821ff5d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007fff`35299f34


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  d812201291a733eb3a234fcb9d87aff8898bb96b

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  23e297066fda31608d7a8696f565352a82569bd8

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  9eef8c7ca0ce66f8b8b34848179f303828cff762

SYMBOL_NAME:  ONE_BIT

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

TARGET_TIME:  2018-08-12T02:19:44.000Z

OSBUILD:  17134

OSSERVICEPACK:  165

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2018-07-06 16:57:56

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180410-1804

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs4_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  1311

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:memory_corruption_one_bit

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e3faf315-c3d0-81db-819a-6c43d23c63a7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```